# Response 422 Error When Post Data in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, postman, load-testing

I have a problem when passing JSON through the POST method in JMeter. All my instance is correct, but why it shows me the error 'instance cannot be null'. I have already tested in postman, it works, but when I used JMeter it didn't. Can you help me to solve this? thanks

the JSON:

```
{
    "$class": "model.Koleksi",
    "koleksiId": "003",
    "nama": "Koleksi 9",
    "jumlah": 9,
    "kondisi": "BAIK",
    "kategori": "Geografika",
    "status": "citrus-fruit-food-fruit-oranges-207085.jpg",
    "keterangan": "Sakti jow",
    "tanggalbentuk": "2020-03-12T12:05:58.113Z",
    "owner": "resource:model.Organisasi#K001",
    "issuer": "resource:model.Organisasi#O001"
 }
```

the error :

```
{"error":{"statusCode":422,"name":"ValidationError","message":"The `Koleksi` instance is not valid. Details: `koleksiId` can't be blank (value: undefined); `nama` can't be blank (value: undefined); `jumlah` can't be blank (value: undefined); `kondisi` can't be blank (value: undefined); `kategori` can't be blank (value: undefined); `status` can't be blank (value: undefined); `keterangan` can't be blank (value: undefined); `tanggalbentuk` can't be blank (value: undefined); `owner` can't be blank (value: undefined); `issuer` can't be blank (value: undefined).","details":{"context":"Koleksi","codes":{"koleksiId":["presence"],"nama":["presence"],"jumlah":["presence"],"kondisi":["presence"],"kategori":["presence"],"status":["presence"],"keterangan":["presence"],"tanggalbentuk":["presence"],"owner":["presence"],"issuer":["presence"]},"messages":{"koleksiId":["can't be blank"],"nama":["can't be blank"],"jumlah":["can't be blank"],"kondisi":["can't be blank"],"kategori":["can't be blank"],"status":["can't be blank"],"keterangan":["can't be blank"],"tanggalbentuk":["can't be blank"],"owner":["can't be blank"],"issuer":["can't be blank"]}},"stack":"ValidationError: The `Koleksi` instance is not valid. Details: `koleksiId` can't be blank (value: undefined); `nama` can't be blank (value: undefined); `jumlah` can't be blank (value: undefined); `kondisi` can't be blank (value: undefined); `kategori` can't be blank (value: undefined); `status` can't be blank (value: undefined); `keterangan` can't be blank (value: undefined); `tanggalbentuk` can't be blank (value: undefined); `owner` can't be blank (value: undefined); `issuer` can't be blank (value: undefined).\n    at /home/sachi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:400:12\n    at Koleksi.<anonymous> (/home/sachi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:578:11)\n    at Koleksi.next (/home/sachi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/hooks.js:93:12)\n    at Koleksi.<anonymous> (/home/sachi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:575:23)\n    at Koleksi.trigger (/home/sachi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/hooks.js:83:12)\n    at Koleksi.Validatable.isValid (/home/sachi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:541:8)\n    at /home/sachi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:396:9\n    at doNotify (/home/sachi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:155:49)\n    at doNotify (/home/sachi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:155:49)\n    at doNotify (/home/sachi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:155:49)\n    at doNotify (/home/sachi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:155:49)\n    at Function.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (/home/sachi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:178:5)\n    at Function.ObserverMixin.notifyObserversOf (/home/sachi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:153:8)\n    at Function.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (/home/sachi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:176:15)\n    at Function.ObserverMixin.notifyObserversOf (/home/sachi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:153:8)\n    at Function.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (/home/sachi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:176:15)"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your JSON is wrong here, the key name should be `"class"` instead of `"$class"`. Could you please double-check.

This correct JSON might be:

```
{
    "class": "model.Koleksi",
    "koleksiId": "003",
    "nama": "Koleksi 9",
    "jumlah": 9,
    "kondisi": "BAIK",
    "kategori": "Geografika",
    "status": "citrus-fruit-food-fruit-oranges-207085.jpg",
    "keterangan": "Sakti jow",
    "tanggalbentuk": "2020-03-12T12:05:58.113Z",
    "owner": "resource:model.Organisasi#K001",
    "issuer": "resource:model.Organisasi#O001"
 }
```

This is a bad request error. The error `'instance cannot be null'` is actually shows for the request body (exact key-value pair) validation.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're not sending the correct [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type) so the server isn't able to "understand" your request.

Try adding a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler which sends the above JSON and configure it to send the aforementioned header like:

[image]

---

In general given the request works fine in Postman you should be able to record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just [configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://support.getpostman.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008893713-How-do-I-configure-Postman-to-work-through-a-proxy-) and execute your request in Postman - JMeter will capture the request with all necessary headers and you will be able to replay it.